# How to get class object by NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

We could use [NSObject class] to get class object, but forgot how to get class object by string, something like [OBJ getClassByNSString: @"NSString"]?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Class myClass = NSClassFromString(@"ClassName");`